# Reading NSNotification userInfo in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

(I'm new to Swift and iOS development in general).

I'm porting some Objective-C code over to Swift and I don't know how to translate this:

```
-(void) fooDidBar:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    Foo* foo = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:BarKey];
    // do stuff with foo
}
```

So far I have this:

```
private func fooDidBar(notification: NSNotification) {
    var foo: Foo = notification.userInfo.objectForKey(BarKey)
}
```

But I get a compiler error:

> /Users/me/src-me/project/FooBarViewController.swift:53:57: Value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' has no member 'objectForKey'

As `userInfo` is declared as an `NSDictionary` in `UIApplicationShortcutItem.h`:

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary<NSString *, id <NSSecureCoding>> *userInfo;
```

...I thought I'd try this:

```
= notification.userInfo[BarKey]
```

but then I get this error:

> /Users/me/src-me/project/FooBarViewController.swift:53:65: Type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' has no subscript members

Answer (score 2):

Your idea to use subscripts was correct, however as you can see by the presence of `?`, the `userInfo` dictionary is [Optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330), meaning that it can be nil (in Objective-C, no distinction is made). Furthermore, Swift's Dictionary is not as lenient with types as NSDictionary, so you'll need to use `as?` to ensure the value is a `Foo` instance as you expect.

You can't directly subscript the optional dictionary, but if you use a [`?` for optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID246), then you can access the value if the dictionary is non-nil. I would also recommend `if let` to access the final value if it's non-nil. (Or you might choose to use `guard let` with a `fatalError` or `return` in case the Foo is not present.)

```
if let foo = notification.userInfo?[BarKey] as? Foo {
    // foo is non-nil (type `Foo`) in here
}
```